# Insert Table Field Values from Dictionary Values with corresponding Keys

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite, database-table

Would it be be possible to insert dictionary values, one at a time into a specific field/column of a sqlite3 database table?
The fields/columns were created with the database in a previous step.

I would prefer to use a for loop, but I haven't found the right sqlite3 "command" that selects the column, which is the same as the dictionary key, and inserts the corresponding values (dictionary value).

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite.connect(db_full_path) as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(db_table))
    db_fields = ','.join('?' for tab in cursor.description) # i.e. ?,?,?,?

    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO {} VALUES ({})"\
        .format(db_table, db_fields), (ORDERED_DATA_VALUES,))
    connection.commit()
```

'cursor.execute' and 'cursor.executemany' both require a predefined number of columns and a sorted list with the same number of items in the right order, which I find less than ideal for my purpose.

I'd much rather iterate over a dictionary and insert the values one at a time, but into the same row:

```
for key, value in NOT_ORDERED_DATA_VALUES.items():
     # insert value into corresponding field/column (key)
```